# Удаление из map пар если значение равно условию

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите пожалуйста имеется карта

```
Map<Integer, Integer> denominations=new HashMap<>();
```

каким образом используя Stream API можно удалить все пары у которых значение равно нулю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
denominations = denominations.entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .filter(e -> e.getValue() != 0)
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                               Map.Entry::getKey,
                               Map.Entry::getValue));
```

но можно намного проще, без стримов

```
denominations.entrySet()
             .removeIf(e -> e.getValue() == 0);
```

Comment: Выдает несоответствие типов. С return не хочет работать.

Comment: второй вариант можно записать как `.values().removeIf( ((Integer)0)::equals );`. Короче, загадочнее и не упадет, если в мапе `null`.